# Do I need a vehicle rental to explore Miami FL?

Tags: usa, planning, tips-and-tricks, miami

I plan on visiting Miami FL for the fist time and for a long weekend as well. I do plan on being able to explore what Miami has to offer, the food, the places, the beach, the nightlife, and anything else I can step into.

I am not a stranger to Florida, there can be a lot of driving involved if you chose so, but my question is solely for the purposes of someone who might be content with **not** leaving Miami at all.

So then I wonder if in order to experience Miami, am I better off relying on a taxi service (such Uber/Lyft for example), or am I better off getting my own car rental for the time I will be there... which is again a long weekend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parking can get really expensive depending on where you go. There are not much parking spaces available in the areas like the coastal regions of Miami Beach. Also, traffic sometimes get congested as well. If you won't be travelling around much (from Key to Key, and into far neighborhoods) then I would suggest you stick with Taxi/Uber/Lyft.

Miami is a big city, so beware that if you want to see a lot of places in a short time, a rental could be your best bet.

Comment: I plan on staying in Miami Beach area so I do not have to think twice about having to drive to the beach, however I do plan on going here and there and soaking in as much as Miami as I can. I can see that Uber may be my best option if I know how to limit myself with where I want to go, such as going to they Keys once or not at all.

Comment: Miami Beach parking prices are really high ($65 overnight), so those combined with rental fee, I believe you should be fine. I have travelled with my own car within Florida, and it was costly, so as long as you are comfortable with Uber, that's your best bet.